# how to Change label Site master in the other forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net C#, I have some problems. I want to change text label in site master when click on button.

In site.master:

```
<asp:label runat="server" id="lblUser">
```

Other forms, I have tried with this code, but not working:

```
((Label)Master.FindControl("lblUser")).Text = "Hello USER";
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question? Or this is additional information?

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
Master.Controls.OfType<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label>.First(c => c.ID == "lblUser").InnerText = "Hello USER";
```

Comment: suggest after OfType is Master.Controls.OfType<>

Comment: Inside the < and > put: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label

Answer (score 0):

What you done is correct that must work.

you can achieve that like

In `Site.Master.cs` make label control public

```
 public string GetUser
 {
        get
        {
            return lblUser.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            lblUser.Text = value;
        }
 }
```

Then set the value to `GetUser` in `otherform.aspx.cs`

```
if(!Ispostback)
{
     Master.GetUser = "Hello USER";
}
```